# How to check if a method was implemented in class Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

I need to check if method was implemented in class.

My classes implements an interface.

Code.

```
  IMyInterface = interface
  ['{538C19EB-22E3-478D-B163-741D6BB29991}']
    procedure Show();
  end;

  TMyClassFormCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure Show();
  end;

  TMyClassFormVendors = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure Show();
  end;
```

....

```
procedure TMyClassFormCustomer.Show;
var
  Form: TFormCustomer;
begin
  Form:= TFormCustomer.Create(nil);
  try
    Form.ShowModal();
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form)
  end;
end;

{ TMyClassFormVendors }

procedure TMyClassFormVendors.Show;
begin
end;
```

It is possible to check if method `TMyClassFormVendors.Show` have implementation?

When a method not have implementation I have disable item in menu

Thanks.

Comment: You mean if its method body has code or is empty, right? Because in both cases it has an implementation. The second one is just empty. Not having an implementation would be having a virtual abstract method. The only way I can think of would be some code analysis but that is more of a hacky approach. I would go with an additional property/function on the Interface called `CanShow` that returns false in the classes that don't do anything in `Show`.

Comment: The compiler won't compile your code unless the method is implemented. I echo Stefan's advice.

Comment: Stefan Glienke you have reason, the method have code but is empty.

I need check method is empty, i will follow your advice.

Thanks

Comment: Why FreeAndNil? The variable is local, nothing else has access to it, it is done at the end of the procedure, so why on earth is the reference nilled? And no, "defensive programming" is not a valid answer, since there is nothing to defend against. FWIW, the others are right: the compiler won't compile the class if the method is not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You could use similar approach as it is used for handling the event methods. So what you want to do is instead of implementing the method directly into your class you add a property which can store a method pointer to the actual method you wanna use. And then at runtime you only check to see if the pointer to such method was already assigned or not.

The code for this would look something like this:

```
type
  //Method type object
  TMyMethod = procedure (SomeParameter: Integer) of object;

  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    //Field storing pointer to the method object
    FMyMethod: TMyMethod;
  protected
    ...
  public
    //proerty used for assigning and accesing the method
    property MyMethod: TMyMethod read FMyMethod write FMyMethod;
  end;
```

When you are designing the method objects you can define how many and which type of parameters you wanna use in that method.

Don't forget you need to assign method to your method property in order to use it. You can do this at any time. You can even unassign it by setting it to nil if needed.
You do this in same way as you do with event methods

```
MyClass.MyMethod := MyProcedure;
```

where MyProcedure needs to have the same parameter structure as the method object type you defined earlier.

And finally you can check to see if methods has been assigned at runtime using:

```
if Assigned(MyClass.MyMethod) then
begin
  //Do something
end
else //Skip forward
```

EDIT: Another advantage of this approach is that your actual method that you use can be defined and written in completely different unit.

Comment: Please can you replace wanna with want to

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I replaced it as you requested

Comment: You missed a couple. The other problem is that asker wants to use interfaces.

Comment: I have overlooked that about interfaces. But can't interfaces also acces properties? If they can I don't see any problem except that the interface should also use property interfacing instead of direct method interfacing.

Comment: You could certainly use this approach with interfaces but you need a little tweaking

Comment: Well to be honest I don't have much expirience with interfaces. So far I managed to do everything by unsing classes.

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of possibilities:

1. If your `TMyClassFormVendors` does not want to do anything in `.Show` then simply don't declare and implement `IMyInterface`. In your code you can then query for that interface with if `Supports(MyClass, IMyInterface)` and react accordingly (Disable Menu entry)
2. If your `IMyInterface` interface actually has more than one method declared, some of which are supported (I don't want to use the word implemented, as all methods have to be implemented) and others are not, then you should better split the interface into several different ones and proceed as described in 1
3. You could also declare and implement another interface "`ICapabilities`" that could have methods like `CanShow` etc. In your code you could then query your class like `if (Myclass as ICapabilities).CanShow` then ...
   I personally would favour 2. as it is the cleanest approach IMO, but it depends on what you want to do specifically